# Display splashscreen & then AppIntro(First time launch) than mainactivity not working

Tags: java, android, xml

I have made android app in which onLaunch I want to show SplashScreen for 3 second & then AppInro(If First time launch in slide) & then MainActivity launches. Actually I have done made splashscreen activity at the end but I set it up all properly but now After splashScreen MainActivity Starts directly. AppIntro not showing(Even in first time launch as well) Before adding SplashScreen activity AppIntro was working fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.introslider">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SpashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Order Medicines"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.welcomeslider.MainActivity"
            //In above line code it shows Can not resolve symbol MainActivity
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

SplashScreen

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class SpashScreen extends Activity {
    private PrefManager prefManager;

    // Splash screen timer
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        /*
         * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
         * want to show case your app logo / company
         */

            @Override
            public void run() {

                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity
                Intent i;

                if (prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
                    i = new Intent(SpashScreen.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
                    prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
                } else {
                    i = new Intent(SpashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                }

                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }

}
```

AppIntro(WelcomeActivity)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;
    private LinearLayout dotsLayout;
    private TextView[] dots;
    private int[] layouts;
    private Button btnSkip, btnNext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Making notification bar transparent
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDots);
        btnSkip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_skip);
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);


        // layouts of all welcome sliders
        // add few more layouts if you want
        layouts = new int[]{
                R.layout.welcome_slide1,
                R.layout.welcome_slide2,
                R.layout.welcome_slide3,
                R.layout.welcome_slide4};

        // adding bottom dots
        addBottomDots(0);

        // making notification bar transparent
        changeStatusBarColor();

        myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);

        btnSkip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                launchHomeScreen();
            }
        });

        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // checking for last page
                // if last page home screen will be launched
                int current = getItem(+1);
                if (current < layouts.length) {
                    // move to next screen
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
                } else {
                    launchHomeScreen();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void addBottomDots(int currentPage) {
        dots = new TextView[layouts.length];

        int[] colorsActive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_active);
        int[] colorsInactive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_inactive);

        dotsLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i] = new TextView(this);
            dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
            dots[i].setTextSize(35);
            dots[i].setTextColor(colorsInactive[currentPage]);
            dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);
        }

        if (dots.length > 0)
            dots[currentPage].setTextColor(colorsActive[currentPage]);
    }

    private int getItem(int i) {
        return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
    }

    private void launchHomeScreen() {
        startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    //  viewpager change listener
    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            addBottomDots(position);

            // changing the next button text 'NEXT' / 'GOT IT'
            if (position == layouts.length - 1) {
                // last page. make button text to GOT IT
                btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.start));
                btnSkip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                // still pages are left
                btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.next));
                btnSkip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }
    };

    /**
     * Making notification bar transparent
     */
    private void changeStatusBarColor() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }

    /**
     * View pager adapter
     */
    public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public MyViewPagerAdapter() {
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position], container, false);
            container.addView(view);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return layouts.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
            return view == obj;
        }


        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            View view = (View) object;
            container.removeView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: code by which you are pushing the screens ?

Comment: @Stallion Do you want me to post SplashScreen code?

Comment: @Stallion I updated my post & inserted code of SpashScreen & AppIntro. Please reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never opening `WelcomeActivity` - you open `MainActivity` directly from `SplashActivity`, so `PrefManager` is never queried.

What you should do in `SplashActivity` is:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        /*
         * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
         * want to show case your app logo / company
         */

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Start your app main activity
            Intent i;

            if (prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
               i = new Intent(SpashScreen.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
               prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
            } else {
               i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class)
            }

            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```

And remove all first time launch checking code from `WelcomeActivity`.

Comment: I made changes as you suggested. Now after SplashScreen app crashes (Unfortunately app has stopped).. I posted Logcat in post

Comment: Hmm it seems impossible that if SplashScreen is specified as the MAIN and LAUNCHER intent in AndroidManifest.xml that it's not opened. Are you sure? I guess your NullPointer is coming from not deleting the prefManager line from the launchHomeScreen() method.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend putting the error not as part of the question. That will confuse anyone else that's coming to help. Put it somewhere like Pastbin, and link in your comments to my answer.

Comment: I updated post now exactly what I done as you said. Please review it once.

Comment: Delete ALL references to prefManager from WelcomeActivity. You are calling prefManager, but it's never initialized, only declared. You don't need it in WelcomeActivity at all.

Comment: I think now I removed all prefManager code from WelcomeActivity. Please check once

Comment: And what happens? Same null pointer? Is your SplashActivity showing?

Comment: After SplashActivity app gets crash

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114647/discussion-between-thefunkyengineer-and-sun).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize `prefManager`, Try initializing it first.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class SpashScreen extends Activity {
    private PrefManager prefManager;

    // Splash screen timer
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        // HERE prefManager INITIALIZED
        prefManager = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        /*
         * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
         * want to show case your app logo / company
         */

            @Override
            public void run() {

                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity
                Intent i;

                if (prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
                    i = new Intent(SpashScreen.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
                    prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
                } else {
                    i = new Intent(SpashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                }

                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize prefManager,this is the right way
this is worked for me.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    try {
        int netStatus = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(getBaseContext());
        if (netStatus == 0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,NoInternetActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        } else {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    PrefManager prefManager = new PrefManager(getApplicationContext());
                    // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                    // Start your app main activity
                    if(prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()){
                        intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
                        prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(true);
                    }else {
                        intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
                    }
                    startActivity(intent);
                    // close this activity
                    finish();
                }
            }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
        }
    }catch (RuntimeException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

}