# android studio - Display intro slide after splash screen

Tags: java, android

As title, I'm doing this base on [Display splashscreen & then AppIntro(First time launch) than mainactivity not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37813591/display-splashscreen-then-appintrofirst-time-launch-than-mainactivity-not-wo) however it just doesn't work and I can't understand the error on logcat. The purpose is to show welcome activity after splashscreen activity. The app itself will work but only showing splash screen and jump straight to login activity instead of intro slide (welcome activity). Would be appreciate if someone can tell me where am I doing wrong.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="firebase.androidhive.info.firebaseauth">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_profile"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_profile"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SignupActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ResetPasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_reset_password"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Splashscreen.java

```
package firebase.androidhive.info.firebaseauth;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
    private PrefManager prefManager;
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 1000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        prefManager = new PrefManager(this);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent i;
                if (prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
                    i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
                    prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
                } else {
                    i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LoginActivity.class);
                }
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }

}
```

Logcat error

```
07-07 22:12:21.294 3464-3464/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-07 22:12:21.362 3464-3464/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-07 22:12:21.362 3464-3464/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-07 22:12:23.494 2706-2706/com.android.vending E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bl.a(3): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
07-07 22:12:23.526 1297-3620/com.estrongs.android.pop E/Cataloger: syncFile:/storage/emulated/0/backups/system/.timestamp
07-07 22:12:23.550 1297-3620/com.estrongs.android.pop E/Cataloger: need not sync path:/storage/emulated/0/backups/system/.timestamp
07-07 22:12:23.550 1297-3620/com.estrongs.android.pop E/Cataloger: syncFile:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.estrongs.android.pop/recomm/setting.download.tmp.tmp
07-07 22:12:23.554 1297-3620/com.estrongs.android.pop E/Cataloger: need not sync path:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.estrongs.android.pop/recomm/setting.download.tmp.tmp
07-07 22:12:23.554 1297-3620/com.estrongs.android.pop E/Cataloger: syncFile:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.estrongs.android.pop/recomm/setting.download.tmp.tmp
07-07 22:12:23.554 1297-3620/com.estrongs.android.pop E/Cataloger: need not sync path:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.estrongs.android.pop/recomm/setting.download.tmp.tmp
07-07 22:12:23.586 3569-3569/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-07 22:12:23.678 1297-3620/com.estrongs.android.pop E/Cataloger: syncFile:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.estrongs.android.pop/recomm/setting.download.tmp.tmp
07-07 22:12:23.678 1297-3620/com.estrongs.android.pop E/Cataloger: need not sync path:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.estrongs.android.pop/recomm/setting.download.tmp.tmp
07-07 22:12:23.678 3569-3569/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-07 22:12:23.678 3569-3569/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-07 22:12:23.742 3615-3615/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'javax.net.ssl.SNIServerName', referenced from method upo.a
07-07 22:12:23.742 3615-3615/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLExtendedSessionImpl', referenced from method upo.a
07-07 22:12:23.742 3615-3615/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLExtendedSessionImpl', referenced from method upo.a
07-07 22:12:23.742 3615-3615/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'javax.net.ssl.SNIHostName', referenced from method upo.b
07-07 22:12:23.750 3615-3615/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'javax.net.ssl.SNIHostName', referenced from method upo.b
07-07 22:12:23.926 1297-3620/com.estrongs.android.pop E/Cataloger: syncFile:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.estrongs.android.pop/recomm/setting.download.tmp.tmp
07-07 22:12:23.938 1297-3620/com.estrongs.android.pop E/Cataloger: need not sync path:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.estrongs.android.pop/recomm/setting.download.tmp.tmp
07-07 22:12:23.938 1297-3620/com.estrongs.android.pop E/Cataloger: syncFile:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.estrongs.android.pop/recomm/setting.download.tmp.tmp
07-07 22:12:23.938 1297-3620/com.estrongs.android.pop E/Cataloger: need not sync path:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.estrongs.android.pop/recomm/setting.download.tmp.tmp
07-07 22:12:23.938 1297-3620/com.estrongs.android.pop E/Cataloger: syncFile:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.estrongs.android.pop/recomm/setting.download.tmp.tmp
07-07 22:12:23.938 1297-3620/com.estrongs.android.pop E/Cataloger: need not sync path:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.estrongs.android.pop/recomm/setting.download.tmp.tmp
07-07 22:12:24.034 3663-3698/? E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/firebase.androidhive.info.firebaseauth-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/firebase.androidhive.info.firebaseauth-1, /system/lib]]
07-07 22:12:24.118 3663-3698/? E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/firebase.androidhive.info.firebaseauth-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/firebase.androidhive.info.firebaseauth-1, /system/lib]]
07-07 22:12:24.154 1297-3620/com.estrongs.android.pop E/Cataloger: syncFile:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.estrongs.android.pop/recomm/setting.download.tmp.tmp
07-07 22:12:24.154 1297-3620/com.estrongs.android.pop E/Cataloger: need not sync path:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.estrongs.android.pop/recomm/setting.download.tmp.tmp
07-07 22:12:24.154 1297-3620/com.estrongs.android.pop E/Cataloger: 重复删除命令
07-07 22:12:24.154 1297-3620/com.estrongs.android.pop E/Cataloger: syncFile:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.estrongs.android.pop/recomm/setting.download.tmp
07-07 22:12:24.154 1297-3620/com.estrongs.android.pop E/Cataloger: need not sync path:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.estrongs.android.pop/recomm/setting.download.tmp
07-07 22:12:24.154 1297-3620/com.estrongs.android.pop E/Cataloger: syncFile:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.estrongs.android.pop/recomm/setting.download.tmp
07-07 22:12:24.158 1297-3620/com.estrongs.android.pop E/Cataloger: need not sync path:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.estrongs.android.pop/recomm/setting.download.tmp
07-07 22:12:24.222 3615-3615/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'iwj', referenced from method iwi.a
07-07 22:12:24.574 3663-3663/firebase.androidhive.info.firebaseauth E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
07-07 22:12:24.578 3663-3663/firebase.androidhive.info.firebaseauth E/OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
07-07 22:12:24.586 3663-3663/firebase.androidhive.info.firebaseauth E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
07-07 22:12:24.586 3663-3663/firebase.androidhive.info.firebaseauth E/OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
07-07 22:12:24.882 3615-3656/com.google.android.gms E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.job.JobScheduler', referenced from method szn.A
07-07 22:12:25.598 3663-3663/firebase.androidhive.info.firebaseauth E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
07-07 22:12:25.902 3615-3806/com.google.android.gms E/Icing: city name for address is empty or is not existed. 
07-07 22:12:26.462 3615-3806/com.google.android.gms E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager', referenced from method qys.a
07-07 22:12:35.178 3663-3698/firebase.androidhive.info.firebaseauth E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/firebase.androidhive.info.firebaseauth-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/firebase.androidhive.info.firebaseauth-1, /system/lib]]
```

PrefManager.java

```
public class PrefManager {
    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context _context;

    // shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Shared preferences file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "androidhive-welcome";

    private static final String IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH = "IsFirstTimeLaunch";

    public PrefManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    public void setFirstTimeLaunch(boolean isFirstTime) {
        editor.putBoolean(IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH, isFirstTime);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean isFirstTimeLaunch() {
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH, true);
    }

}
```

Comment: have you commit after `prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);` this?

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what are you meaning.

Comment: I took the 'SharedPreferences' code from another tutorial, I just checked and there is no pref.commit() inside only editor.commit(), I've edit the post and put prefmanager code inside @Ninja